# Why Android Studio finds error in XmlResourceParser

Tags: android, xmlresourceparser

Simple code for parsing activity_main.xml

```
XmlResourceParser xmlResourceParser = res.getXml(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Android Studio finds error "Expected resource of type xml", but runs this code and app works correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses an inspector to help you find an error, it expects a resource type 'R.xml.nameresource', obviously works because steps still an xml. For delete error you can disable inspection 'Constant and Resource Type Mismatches' options or add a xml folder in your res folder, create a new xml file and copy your content

Answer (score 0):

The resource type of that resource is technically not `xml`, instead it is actually `layout`.  I think it must still be working because layout files are also XML files.